# Doubt from Spivak's proof of inverse function theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, inverse-function-theorem

[image]

why must $y^i-f^i(x)=0$ for *all* $i$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the equation above can be represented as
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
D_jf^i(x)
\end{bmatrix} ^T
\begin{bmatrix}
    2(y^1-f^1(x))\\
\vdots \\
2(y^n-f^n(x))
\end{bmatrix} = \vec0.
$$
If matrix $[D_jf^i(x)]^T$ have non-zero determinant (i.e. the inverse exists) then the system must have trivial solution since one can multiply equation above by its inverse. So we have $y^i-f^i(x) = 0$ for all $i=1,\dots,n$.

Comment: It doesn't affect the idea, but shouldn't there be a transpose on the matrix $[D_jf^i(x)]$?

Comment: @Snowball I see, Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

The equation can be rewritten as a matrix equation: Denote $D_jf^i=M_j^i$ and $2(y^i-f^i)=v^i$, then we have $M_j^i v^i=0$, or $M \vec{v}=\vec{0}$. In other words, it is of the form $(\text{matrix})\cdot (\text{vector})=(\text{zero vector})$.

The assertion that $D_j f^i$ has nonzero determinant implies that $M$ is invertible, hence the equation can only be satisfied if $\vec{v}$ itself is the zero vector, i.e. all components vanish, i.e. $v^i=0$ for all $i$.